# Expanding 2 partitions with other partitions surrounding them

Tags: ubuntu, windows-10, partitioning, ssd, gparted

I am upgrading my Dell XPS 13 9333's SSD from 128gb to 512gb. I have been able to get all the stuff over to my new SSD (my old one is in a USB enclosure), but I cannot expand my Windows 10 (/dev/sda5) and Ubuntu 16.04 (/dev/sda8) partitions because have a rather tricky partition arrangement. This is what gparted reports:
[image: My partition layout]
/dev/sda10 is a empty partition I created, to see if creating a partition will help me expand another partition. 
The partition at the end is my /dev/sda10, to the right of that is unallocated space. 
/dev/sda7 is for Intel Rapid Start on windows, there are also a few other various partitions for windows to use. 
I have tried to expand the Windows and Ubuntu partitions, but it doesn't let me. I believe this is because the partitions are not next to the unallocated space. How could I easily expand the Windows partition (/dev/sda5) to ~300gb, and Ubuntu (/dev/sda8) to whatever is left? Please give very specific instructions about how to do this task, because I am a beginner to gparted and cannot understand instructions from other sites about how to move partitions.

Answer (score 1):

You can move partitions in order to align the unallocated space with the partitions you want to expand. See [this answer](https://superuser.com/a/528946/537463) for advice pertaining to a similar question.

The `GParted Manual` (`Contents` in the gparted `Help` menu) explains how to move a partition in the `Advanced Partition Actions` section, within `Working with Partitions`. You can choose the `Resize/Move` item in the `Partition` menu, for an unmounted partition.

Comment: How do I move a partition? I haven't been able to find a clear explanation on the internet.